# Submit Recurly form again, to restart an expired subscription?

Tags: ruby, recurly

I create a Recurly subscription using the V3 form components, and I'm storing the unique ID recurly generates, in my Rails backend.

I'm able to cancel/expire subscriptions (using the `client.terminate_subscription` method from my backend, using the unique Recurly ID).

However, if my user re-submits the recurly form with their credit card details, it creates an entirely new subscription.

Can I just resume the previous (now expired) subscription?